# Yii2 Distinct Rows in gridview

Tags: php, gridview, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am unable to get the unique results in grid view.

What I have done so far is:

```
$query = Products::find()->select('id_product_provider')->distinct();
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query'      => $query,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 100
        ]
    ]);
```

The result is what I wanted, but grid view is not showing all other columns than `some-column`,

Output:
[image]
I dont know, the result is what I wanted to be. But the grid view is not showing all other required colums like name, description etc.

I update the query to following:

```
$query = Products::find()->select('other_columns,some_column')->distinct();
```

the result is not unique by `some_column`.
[image]

Controller Code:

```
$searchModel  = new ProductsSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel'  => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
```

And view is:

```
GridView::widget(['dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                               'filterModel'  => $searchModel,
                               'columns'      => [['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                                                  ['attribute' => 'Image',
                                                   'format'    => 'html',
                                                   'value'     => function ($data) {
                                                       return Html::img($data->image, ['width' => '100']);
                                                   },],
                                                  ['attribute'      => 'name',
                                                   'format'         => 'raw',
                                                   'value'          => function ($data) {
                                                       return strlen($data->name) > 25 ?
                                                           html_entity_decode(substr($data->name, 0, 25) . '...') :
                                                           html_entity_decode($data->name);
                                                   },
                                                   'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'max-width: 200px;']],
                                                  ['attribute'      => 'description',
                                                   'format'         => 'raw',
                                                   'value'          => function ($data) {
                                                       return strlen($data->description) > 25 ?
                                                           html_entity_decode(substr($data->description, 0, 25) . '...') :
                                                           html_entity_decode($data->description);
                                                   },
                                                   'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'max-width: 200px;']],
                                                  ['attribute' => 'price',
                                                   'format'    => 'text',
                                                   'value'     => function ($data) {
                                                       return html_entity_decode($data->price);
                                                   },],

                                                  ['attribute'      => 'price_category',
                                                   'format'         => 'text',
                                                   'value'          => function ($data) {
                                                       return strip_tags(html_entity_decode($data->price_category));
                                                   },
                                                   'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'max-width: 100px;']],
                                                  ['attribute'      => 'product_category',
                                                   'format'         => 'text',
                                                   'filter'         => $categories,
                                                   'value'          => function ($data) {
                                                       return strlen($data->product_category) > 25 ?
                                                           html_entity_decode(substr($data->product_category, 0, 25) . '...') :
                                                           html_entity_decode($data->product_category);
                                                   },
                                                   'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'max-width: 150px;']],
                                                  ['attribute'      => 'provider',
                                                   'format'         => 'text',
                                                   'value'          => function ($data) {
                                                       return strlen($data->provider) > 25 ?
                                                           html_entity_decode(substr($data->provider, 0, 25) . '...') :
                                                           html_entity_decode($data->provider);
                                                   },
                                                   'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'max-width: 150px;'],
                                                   'filter'         => $providers,],
                                                  ['attribute'      => 'universe',
                                                   'format'         => 'text',
                                                   'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'max-width: 100px;'],
                                                   'filter'         => ['fabrics' => 'fabrics', 'wool' => 'wool', 'paper' => 'paper'],],
                                                  'id_product_provider',
                                                  ['class'    => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                                                   'header'   => 'Action',
                                                   'template' => '{info}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{detail}',
                                                   'buttons'  => ['info'   => function ($url, $model) {
                                                       return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', $model->url, ['title'  => Yii::t('app', 'Info'),
                                                                                                                                                    'target' => '_blank']);
                                                   },
                                                                  'detail' => function ($url, $model) {
                                                                      $url = str_replace(' ', '-', $model->universe) . '/' . str_replace(' ', '-', $model->product_category) . '/' . $model->slug . '/' . $model->id;
                                                                      $url = Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontEnd->createUrl($url);


                                                                      return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span>', $url, ['title'  => Yii::t('app', 'Info'),
                                                                                                                                                                     'target' => '_blank']);
                                                                  }],]],]);
        ?>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The result is  distinc by the combination of columns you provided in select   (and not only by some_column)

in this case  `$query = Products::find()->select('other_columns,some_column')->distinct();`  by `other_columns, some_column`-

You can check the query really executed  using this

```
  var_dump(Products::find()->select('other_columns,some_column')->distinct()
      ->createCommand()->getSql());
```

then your query should be

```
$query = Products::find()->
     select('name,  description, price, price_category')->distinct();
```

but if you need  only a rows you shuld use aggregation function and group by not distinct

```
$query = Products::find()->
     select('max(name) as name,  
          max(description) as description,
          max(price) as price, 
          max(price_category) as price_category ')->groupBy(['id_product_provider']);
```

Comment: Yeah, I just need uniness by only one column, but displaying all columns in grid view. Its not showing up.

Comment: I don't understand  .. should you update you question with proper data sample e and the expected . result ..

Comment: Grid view is not showing all other columns, but shows only the distinctness column.

Comment: I repeat .. your comments are not clear to me .. if  you could show  proper data sample e and the expected . result .  . and  the gridview code  .. i can try to understand ..

Comment: Ok ..I begin to understand .. please update your question with the gridview code and the related  controller/action that you are currently using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127816/discussion-between-tnc-and-scaisedge).